# Avoid code-duplication in the controller beforeInterceptor-blocks in Grails

Tags: grails, controller, dry

I have the following identical code-block in all my controllers' beforeInterceptor blocks:

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
  request.someField = Foo.someFoo(request)
  if (!request.someField) {
    redirect(...)
    return
  }
}
```

Repeating the exact same code fragment in all controllers violates DRY. Is there some standard Grails way to define a "global" beforeInterceptor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [Filter](http://grails.org/doc/1.1.x/guide/single.html#6.6%20Filters) can be used to apply before/after logic across a group of controllers, a URI or to a specific action.

Comment: Hi, the link is no longer online, can't be found in the Google's cache and I cannot see the equivalent in the current version of the documentation - https://grails.org/single-page-documentation.html . Maybe you know where it can be found?